# ¿Cuál es la función de un archivo .edmx en operaciones crud?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo un par de dudas sobre la función de este archivo .edmx generado con **Entity F.** específicamente en operaciones **CRUD**, leí su definición en la página oficial pero aún no logro despejar dudas:

1. ¿Sustituye a la base de datos dentro del proyecto?
2. ¿Es el "puente" entre una consulta y la base de datos?

[image: archivo.edmx]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El archivo .edmx es propio de entity framework y puede decirse que es el mapeo de tu base de datos convertida a un lenguaje de programación en este caso c#.

No sustituye a la base de datos simplemente es el modelo de tu base de datos segun como tu la hayas definido.

Respecto a la segunda duda que tienes, cuando tu generas un edmx estas creando y definiendo tu modelo como lo tienes en base de datos, como deberia ser la comunicación, puede ser un puente si quieres verlo asi, pero mas bien el modelo edmx es tu modelo visual de bd convertido a clases(entidades), con herencia(relaciones) y estas a su vez, te ayudaran a llegar a todas las propiedades(campos) de todas las clases(entidades).

Comment: Cuando alguien vota -1 es mas constructivo decir el que no le parece adecuado en la respuesta para que el usuario pueda corregirlo en si asi lo considera

Answer (score 4):

El `EDMX` representa el modelo visual del mapping que realiza `EF` entre las entidades del negocio y la base de datos. Basicamente es un `XML` que mapea las entidades a la estructura de la db.

El `EDMX` es un modelo visual que permite definir `Database First` o `Model First`.

[EF Designer para una nueva base de datos (Model First)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/data/jj205424)

[EF Designer para una base de datos existente (Database First)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/data/jj206878)

**>>Sustituye a la base de datos dentro del proyecto?**

No para nada, el `edmx` es solo el mapeo de las entidades con la estructura de la db.
Es quien define el contexto que EF requiere, generando codigo en base al mapping.

**>>Es el "puente" entre una consulta y la base de datos?**

Casi, no es tanto a una consulta sino a una entidad de negocio. 
Es quien define que clase mapea con cual tabla y que propiedad con cual columna. Tambien defines la navegación entre as entidades, y como mapear la herencia (si es que la hay)

Comment: Podria decirse que me evita crear las clases ejm: producto.cs proveedor.cs en la carpeta models, y este los crea automaticamente segun la Base de datos (si es existente), por que acabo de probar operaciones crud generadas automa. con telerik y no tenia clases creadas manualmente, solo las incluidas en .edmx, sé que me editaran esto: Muchas gracias Leandroo!

Comment: @Miko en realidad usar las clases que genera EF como model de las view de asp.net mvc no es lo recomendable, deberias trabajar en capas y convertir la entidad de EF en otra que use asp.net para las view. Que pasa si quieres agregar atributos de DataAnnotation en las entidades de la view para aplicar validaciones? ahi se complica si usas las mismas entidades,por eso no se recomienda, aunque se que es lo mas rapido para desarrollar, para convertir de uan entidad a otra podrias ayudarte con la libreria autompper.